# x86-64 function calls using stack gdb debugging error cannot access memory at location xxx

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, x86-64

I am writing a program calling 2 pre-given functions min.c and conv.c, also of course a main.c
min.s goes as follows:

```
.file   "min.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  min
    .type   min, @function
min:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    cmpl    %esi, %edi
    movl    %esi, %eax
    cmovle  %edi, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   min, .-min
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

conv.c:

```
char conv(char *, char *, int);

char conv(char *x, char *h, int n) {
    char ret = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret += x[i] * h[n-i-1];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

min.c:

```
int min(int, int);

int min(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) return a;
    return b;
}
```

and conv.s goes as follows:

```
.file   "conv.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  conv
    .type   conv, @function
conv:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    testl   %edx, %edx
    jle .L4
    movslq  %edx, %rax
    leaq    -1(%rsi,%rax), %rcx
    leaq    -2(%rsi,%rax), %rsi
    leal    -1(%rdx), %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    subq    %rax, %rsi
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    subq    $1, %rcx
    addq    $1, %rdi
    mulb    1(%rcx)
    addl    %eax, %edx
    cmpq    %rcx, %rsi
    jne .L3
    movl    %edx, %eax
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L4:
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   conv, .-conv
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

also my small basic piece of code is trying to just go after a pre-given algorithm:

```
    for i from 0 to n+m-2 do
ladj <- min(i+1, m)
radj <- m - min(m+n-(i+1), m)
result[i] <- conv(x + (i+1-ladj), h + radj, ladj-radj)
```

so i wrote:

```
    .globl conv_arr
    conv_arr:
        movq $0, %rax       # zero out the result

        movq $0, %rbx       # %rbx is set to 0 to be the counter for the loop, i.e. int i

        addq %rsi, %rbp
        addq %rcx, %rbp
        subq $2, %rbp       # 3 lines of code to set a limit for the counter, i.e. n + m - 2

    loop: # loop label
        cmpq %rbx, %rbp     # comparing to keep the loop in scope from i = 0 to n + m - 2

        jle return      # jump to return label if the counter reaches the limit

        pushq %rdi
        pushq %rsi      # saving all the registers before calling function min( int, int)

        movq %rbx, %r10     # copying the value of %rbx into the value of %r10

        addq $1, %r10       # adding 1 to the value of %r10

        movq %r10, %rdi     # changing the value of %rdi ( in this case the first parameter
                    # to the function min() ) to i + 1

        movq %rcx, %rsi     # changing the value of %rsi ( in this case the second parameter to
                    # the function min() ) to m

        call min        # calling the function min() with the two parameters %rdi, %rsi

        popq %rsi       
        popq %rdi       # restoring the values of %rdi and %rsi to their initial values

        movq %rax, %r12     # copying the value of the result from function min() to %r12,
                    # the register which is now set up to be the value of ladj

        pushq %rdi
        pushq %rsi      # saving the values of %rdi and %rsi before calling function min()

        movq %rcx, %rdi     # copying the value of %rcx ( int m ) into the value of %rdi

        addq %rsi, %rdi     # adding the value of %rsi ( int n ) into the value of %rdi

        subq %rbx, %rdi     # subtracting the value of %rbx ( int i ) from the value of %rdi

        subq $1, %rdi       # subtracting 1 from the value of %rdi

        movq %rcx, %rsi     # copying the value of %rcx ( int m ) into the value of %rsi

        call min        # calling the function min() with two parameters %rdi, %rsi

        popq %rsi
        popq %rdi       # restoring the values of %rdi and %rsi to their initial values

        movq %rcx, %r13     # copying the value of %rcx ( int m ) into the value of 

                    # register %r13

        subq %rax, %r13     # subtracting the value of %rax ( min( m + n - ( i + 1 ), m ) )
                    # from the value of %rcx ( m )

        movq %r13, %r14     # copying the value of %r13 ( m - min( m + n - ( i + 1 ), m )                   # ) into the value of %r14, the register which is now set up 
                    # to be the value of radj

        pushq %rdi
        pushq %rsi      
        pushq %rdx
        pushq %rcx      # saving the values of %rdi, %rsi, %rdx and %rcx before calling 
                    # function conv( char*, char*, int )

        addq %rbx, %rdi     # adding the value of %rbx ( i ) to the value of %rdi ( char* x )

        addq $1, %rdi       # adding 1 to the value of %rdi

        subq %r12, %rdi     # subtracting the value of %r12 ( ladj ) from the value of %rdi

        movq %rdx, %rsi     # copying the value of %rdx ( char* h ) to the value of %rsi

        addq %r14, %rsi     # adding the value of %r14 ( radj ) to the value of %rsi

        movq %r12, %rdx     # copying the value of %r12 ( ladj ) to the value of %rdx

        subq %r14, %rdx     # subtracting the value of %r14 ( radj ) from the value of %rdx

        call conv       # calling the function conv() with three parameters %rdi, %rsi
                    # and %rdx

        popq %rcx
        popq %rdx
        popq %rsi
        popq %rdi       # restoring the values of %rdi, %rsi, %rdx and %rcx to their                    # initial values

        movq %rax, %r8      # copying the value of %rax ( result after calling function conv()                  # ) into the value of the index that %r8 ( char* result) is                     # pointing to

        incq %rbx       # incrementing the value of %rbx ( i ) by 1

        incq %r8        # incrementing the value of %r8 ( char* result ) according to the
                    # value of %rbx ( i ), i.e. result[i]

        jmp loop        # jump back to the loop label when all the procedures are done

    return: # return label
        ret
```

all the comments are given to keep track of what i was attempting to do, i know it needs a lot more research and attention. 
When i ran the program it gave a segmentation fault, i ran gdb with it and it says the error was cannot access memory at address xxx:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

```
0x0000000000400757 in conv (x=0x601050 <signal> "",
      h=0xffffffff80601050 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff601050> n=15) at conv.c:8.

8                ret += x[i] * h[n-i-1];
```

I tried breakpoints at lines using conv.c and it went backwards when counting, i.e. when the program reached n=3 it started going back to n=2, n=1 and then all the way back to n=-12 even further.

****IF ANYONE HAS ANY SUGGESTIONS I WOULD REALLY APPRECIATE IT****.

Comment: You compiled with optimization enabled, so you won't necessarily get consistent debugging for local variables.  But normally debug info can't track vars in regs, so I'm surprised you got anything at all for `print n`, because the function is doing `subq    $1, %rcx` for a pointer to the end, and `addq    $1, %rdi` for the forward pointer (`x[i]`).  But anyway, the function doesn't record its incoming args anywhere, so there's not much GDB can do to recover them.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry but i don't really understand where you're coming from (i'm really new at this, this is the first x86-64 course i've taken and i haven't done too much research on how gdb would work on special cases), i haven't done anything concerning to %rcx, right??? Or is it the compiler that is affecting it??? And also if i do addq $1, %rdi should it increment (move) the char* x pointer by 1 index??? But on top of it all, i really appreciate your attention in this.

Comment: I'm talking about the compiler-generated code that implements `conv()`.  Your program crashes inside `conv()`, so the current stack frame at that point is `conv`'s stack frame.  Presumably you're passing it bad pointers, or an actually-negative `n`, but that's a lot easier to check with a debugger than by reading your long and complicated calling code that spends a lot of instructions pushing and popping, instead of using some call-preserved regs for values that you want to survive a function call.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll look into the conv's stack frame and try minimizing the pushing and popping, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'd recommend writing your caller in C and looking at what a compiler does, and compare that to what you wrote.  Watch how it saves/restores registers like RBX once, and uses them inside the loop.  (Because the calling convention says RBX is call-preserved).  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) and other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info